# What is the need of location pragmas

Tags: c, gcc

Recently I have checked a Legacy project (developed before 10 years).

I came across `#pragma DATA_SECTION`. Almost every global variable is added 
to particular data section. 
Don't know the reason why globals are specifically moved to DATA_SECTION?

In Recent days when we develop a C application we are not worrying about DATA Sections and all.

So What is the reason for usage of location pragmas in old days and not used 
nowadays?

Comment: This depends heavily on platform you are compiling for. Such pragmas are sometimes necessary even today on embedded code.

Comment: Tell us more about the platform this code is intended for.

Comment: Yes . It is an embedded Platform (TMS320 DSP) having unified memory model. May i know why it is necessary only for embedded platforms ...

Comment: @Balaganesh.V There's plenty of situations. Memory-mapped registers, hardware constants in flash with specific meaning (SP value, clock settings etc), placement of ISRs, separate "no-init" sections of RAM, separating memory for application and library code, DMA buffers, bootloaders. And so on and so on. Nobody can tell why the person who wrote your code needed it, in particular nobody can tell without any context or examples provided.

Comment: @Balaganesh.V `In Recent days when we develop a C application we are not worrying about DATA Sections and all.` **WE???** Say **you**. If you write simple enough embedded code, you do not need to worry. But what about more complicated memory layouts & logical organisations & user startup codes?

Answer (score 3):

`#pragma` is used when a compiler does something beyond the scope of the C standard. If the code is compiled with another compiler which doesn't recognize the `#pragma`, the line will simply be ignored.

`#pragma DATA_SECTION NAME` together with `#pragma DATA_SECTION DEFAULT` are used on some embedded systems compilers when you need to allocate variables in a particular memory section, such as on a specific address. `NAME` in this example is the custom name of the memory segment.

(It is similar to `__declspec(section "NAME")` that you may find on other compilers.)

I suspect that this is from Freescale/NXP Codewarrior, where `#pragma DATA_SECTION NAME` means: put all static storage duration read/write variables in section `NAME` from here on.

The reason why you would do this depends on the application. In embedded systems, it is very common that you need to place variables at certain addresses.

Comment: Yes. Iam seeing it in a embedded application.  Need to know why variables are placed in Data section

Comment: @Balaganesh.V We are no clairvoyants. Read the documentation and ask the authors. That's all speculation from here.

Comment: @Balaganesh.V if you do not understand why, you do not need it. When you need it for the first time - you will then understand why